# Why use parent::initialize in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Why I need to use **`parent::initialize()`** on initialize method from Controller,  although it works without this?

using: cakephp 3

Thanks
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: parent just runs the parent method from the Override method.  See you are overriding the `initialize()` method but there may be "stuff" in the parent's method that is essential, so because it's inaccessible now ( because of the override ) you use `parent::method()` to access it, and run the code there

Comment: its important to note that sometimes the order in which you call the parents method can matter  for example
`your code;`
`parent::method();`
OR
`parent::method();`
`your code;`
If there is something in parent that `your code` depends on you have to call parent first, this seems obvious. But it's easy to overlook it, because the code 'bits' likely exist in 2 separate files.

Answer (score 2):

These are php OOP basics: http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php

> You may find yourself writing code that refers to variables and functions in base classes. This is particularly true if your derived class is a refinement or specialisation of code in your base class.
>
> Instead of using the literal name of the base class in your code, you should be using the special name parent, which refers to the name of your base class as given in the extends declaration of your class. By doing this, you avoid using the name of your base class in more than one place. Should your inheritance tree change during implementation, the change is easily made by simply changing the extends declaration of your class.

```
class A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
        echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
```

If *you* need to call is up to *your* implementation. However, in a framework it is most of the time a good idea to call parent methods when overriding methods, to make sure the logic up in the chain is called. Read the php manual, it comes with examples.

Comment: It's actually just a copy and paste from the link of the documentation. Even the example is taken from there. People don't read docs anymore these days. :(